# fetch static file with Apollo and SSR

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch, apollo, server-side-rendering

I want to fetch a json dynamically in a component and in SSR mode. I'm using Apollo Client and a GraphQL api.
With Apollo useQuery hook, we can fetch graphql api with SSR mode, is it possible to use useQuery to fetch a json in ssr way too ? or another method ? fetch api is only on client side